# How to execute a GRASS module developed in Python?

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass.script

I am following the [FOSS4G-E 2015 tutorial](https://github.com/wenzeslaus/python-grass-addon) on how to develop GRASS modules with Python. The minimum template given in this tutorial is this script:

```
%%file r.viewshed.points.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

#%module
#% description: Compute and analyze viewsheds
#% keyword: raster
#% keyword: viewshed
#%end

import grass.script as gscript

def main():
    gscript.parser()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which at face value looks pretty ok. However, when I try to run it I get a strange message, and GRASS hangs up:

```
GRASS 7.2.0 (nc_spm_08_grass7):~/git/python-grass-addon > ./r.viewshed.points.py --help
./r.viewshed.points.py: line 1: fg: no job control
```

What is the exact way of executing this template module?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the script is actually an instruction to Jupyter. It must be left out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#%module
#% description: Compute and analyze viewsheds
#% keyword: raster
#% keyword: viewshed
#%end

import grass.script as gscript

def main():
    gscript.parser()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For a more complete template, check this section https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/g.parser.html#easy-creation-of-a-script